# How to list all imagens on the device?

Tags: android, file, file-io

How do I get a list of all images in my android device?

**update:** Maybe there is a [Content Provicer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) for all the images on the device.. (studying)

**update:** Getting hot, [MediaStore.Images](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.html) have the information.. now looking for how to get it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi tom you are on the right !
this is an example implementing Asynctask =)

[Displaying Images from SD Card](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/11/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html)

Comment: hi Tom whats on the line 157?

Comment: As last thing, I'm just trying to understand why he execute the load as an AsyncTask. I put the code on a simples method and it works fine..

Comment: using Asynctask is a good practice, you will have long background operations while publish your results on the UI, cool!.